# How to align asp:Label's text top in his span?

Tags: asp.net, css, vertical-alignment

I have problem with generating of `<asp:Label>` in different browsers. For example in IE is text on top of span generated by Label; in Opera it is in the middle.. when i set display to inline:

[image: screenshot]

Can I somehow unite differences and set the same aligning in both browsers? (I want to set top align in Opera too) I was not able to find any solution working for me. Thanks.

Comment: Without seeing some sample HTML (or an ASP.NET form/view fragment) and CSS, the question is really difficult to answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is html generated in Opera:

<span id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_fvProduct_lblAmount" style="display:inline-block;color:Black;font-family:Gabriola;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;height:20px;">1200</span>

and this one copied from IE
<span id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_fvProduct_lblAmount" style="height: 20px; color: black; font-family: Gabriola; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; display: inline-block;">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly what I imagined, but with this hack I can position text special for IE and the result is what i needed. 
So the position of label in his span is still different to other browsers, but I can move entire span.

http://blog.vervestudios.co/blog/post/2011/05/13/IE9-Only-CSS-Hack.aspx

Thanks to all for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) file would help you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, i will definitely use this, but I'm afraid it does not solve my problem